# How to render custom form fields on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So by default RoR has Form Helpers that let you render form fields easily eg

```
<% form_for @article do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Awesome but let's say i want to render all my forms in a different way let's say i want to add different things

1. Bootstrap classes to fields `form-control`
2. Red asterisk next to the label if it's required.
3. `data-toggle="validator"`

Just to name a few, What would be the best way i can achieve these?

Comment: Some simple Googling will get you started down the right road. Once you've tried some specific things, come back and ask a more focused question (or questions) showing us what you've tried, what is unclear, etc.

Comment: @jvillian What isn't clear here? Pardon my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining your own custom form builder.

Refer to [Form Builder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) for more info.